# Twisted normals with the Three.js normal shader - r.58

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm attempting to use the Three.js r.58 normal shader to make a displacement map. I have it displacing correctly, but the lighting doesn't seem to be respecting the post-displacement normals, even when I use computeTangents().

When I turn off the displacement, I see that the default normals are definitely funny. Here's a top view of a sphere, lit from the side (the white dot marks a pointLight):

[image: Top view of sphere with normal shader, lit from the side]

And here's a demo page:
http://meetar.github.io/three.js-normal-map-0/index0.html

What's causing this? And is there documentation for the Three.js normal shader anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not passing in a normalMap, which is required. Try passing in a flat one.
2. `ComputeTangents()` can do strange things on vertices that have discontinuous UVs -- like at the north pole.
3. The code is the doucmentation. :-)

Comment: A response to "The code is the documentation": http://www.commonsense4commonpeople.net/2008/11/the-code-is-the-documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

The "twisted" normals are the result of each vertex normal being evaluated as the RGB value `(255, 255, 255)`, which corresponds to the tangent space XYZ coordinates `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`. This seems to be the default behavior when a three.js normalmap material is used without passing a normal map. If you pass an all-white normal map, you'll see the same behavior.

To pass a normal map to the normalmap shader, add this line to your uniform declarations:

```
uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'normalmap.png' );
```

To pass a "flat" normal map, make your "normalmap.png" solid `(128, 128, 255)` lavender, which normalizes to tangent-space coordinates `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`.

For a great breakdown of normal maps including lots of examples, check out this link: http://wiki.polycount.com/NormalMap/