# How do I update normals after positioning vertices in vertex shader?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

**Short version:** I'm manipulating the position of vertices in a vertex shader, but when I calculate the normals based on the vertex `position`, the normals are calculated based on the original vertex position. Shouldn't the vertex shader know where the new vertices are?

**Long version:** I'm writing a custom shader in three.js R.58 based on the three.js `normalmap` shader. I'm passing a flat texture (0.5, 0.5, 1.0 lavender) to the shader as a `tNormal`, and then setting the position of a `planeGeometry`'s vertices in the vertex shader to bend it into a sphere.

Here's the bit of the vertex shader where normals are calculated:

```
vec3 newPosition = mix( position, goalPosition, mixAmount );

vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;

vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );

//tangent and binormal vectors
vTangent = normalize( normalMatrix * tangent.xyz );

vBinormal = cross( vNormal, vTangent ) * tangent.w;
vBinormal = normalize( vBinormal );
```

This code works for default sphereGeometry and planeGeometry. However, when I deform a plane into a sphere, the shading doesn't work as expected – the fragment shader seems to think the sphere is still a plane – or something.

Here's the sphere with a pointLight, showing warping specular highlight:

[image]

Demo: http://meetar.github.io/planebending/plane_bending.html

And that only shows up if the original plane is facing the pointlight - at other rotations, the sphere is black no matter where the camera is, suggesting that the plane normals are still somehow being calculated as though the vertices hadn't been repositioned.

I've set `geometry.dynamic = true` as well as `geometry.normalsNeedUpdate` and `geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate`, and I'm calling `geometry.computeTangents()`, but nothing seems to work.

I was under the impression that in GLSL, the components of the scene used to calculate normals (such as the `normalMatrix` and the `tangent`) take into account any vertex manipulation by the vertex shader. What am I missing? Is this something specific to three.js?

**Edit:**

Checking in the console, I see that every face in the deformed plane still has a worldspace normal of (0, 0, 1), as it did in its undeformed state, as opposed to a sphereGeometry instance, whose normals vary depending on their orientation.

Here's another demonstration: these two objects have the same material. The left is SphereGeometry, the right is a deformed PlaneGeometry. When the plane deforms, the normals don't seem to update to reflect the faces' new orientation, and the specular doesn't show up properly.

[image]

Demo: http://meetar.github.io/planebending/plane_bending_06.html

Comment: Nothing is done automatically in the vertex shader; that is actually the point. Some things happen automatically afterwards (e.g. perspective division), but normalization of output varyings is not one of those things. In the fixed-function pipeline, there was a feature to automatically re-normalize, but that does not apply in WebGL.

Comment: That said, generally in the vertex the way you tackle this is by transforming the lighting vectors into tangent space using the Tangent, Bitangent and Normal vectors. Then all lighting calculation is done in the fragment shader in the same coordinate space as the normal is sampled in (tangent space). There are alternatives, such as transforming the normals into world/view space in the fragment shader but that approach is more expensive and primarily used for deferred shading. *Unfortunately, without including the shaders relevant to this question, I cannot write an actual answer.*

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll modify my question to try to make more sense.

Comment: How does this differ from your prior question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528878/compute-normals-from-displacement-map-in-three-js-r-58? Also, I would advise you to update to the current version of three.js.

Comment: Displacement and displaced normals work fine in this case, but the apparent normals on the base shape do not. Updating breaks everything – I'll stick with incremental change for now. Once I understand this I may attempt an upgrade – unless normals are calculated differently in the newest version?

Comment: I've updated to r65. The problem persists.

Comment: r.65 +1 :-)  With all due respect, it appears you copied code from elsewhere and you do not really understand what it is doing. If that is the case, you need to start over and experiment with simpler examples until you understand every step.

Comment: @WestLangley Quite likely. In your understanding, in GLSL, do the components of the scene used to calculate normals (such as the normalMatrix and the tangent) take into account any vertex manipulation by the vertex shader?

Comment: No. The data is one-way in this case -- from the CPU to the GPU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short version:** You can't!

**Long version:** Even if the vertex shader is moving the vertices, it only knows the updated position of the *current vertex* – to calculate new face normals, it would have to know the updated position of all the neighbor vertices, and so far, WebGL doesn't allow that.

Although the vertex shader does calculate normals, they're all based on the *original normals*, which are passed to the vertex shader along with the original vertex positions. Those calculations are mostly just the standard normal-related things required for the fragment shader, such as accounting for light position, transformations, and so on, and they all assume that the vertices are going to hold still relative to each other in object space.

It's relatively easy to update normals with the CPU and pass those to the vertex shader, but if you must do it in the vertex shader, there are some sneaky ways to fake it, such as using [bump maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528878/compute-normals-from-displacement-map-in-three-js-r-58); and if the vertices are being moved based on any kind of parametric computation, you can [generate some neighbors on the fly and check the normal between them](http://tonfilm.blogspot.com/2007/01/calculate-normals-in-shader.html), which is definitely cheating.

Sources:

- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1478#issuecomment-4450787
- http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/

Comment: GLSL actually does allow what you described, in Geometry Shaders. There is a type of primitive known as adjacency for this purpose. But since we are discussing WebGL, you should forget I even mentioned GS.

Comment: In regard to calculation of normals in a vertex shader using a function, I'm not sure it's 'cheating' as such.  It's just not a generic solution to the problem. Helpful links though.